# Is there a shorter way to remove the first two values in a list?

Tags: python, min, average, python-3.3

I want to find the sum of a list not including the first two values:

```
values.remove(min(values))

values.remove(min(values))

avg = sum(values) / len(values)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: What is that you intend to perform?

Comment: And why would you divide by 1?

Comment: `sum(qList)/1 == sum(qList)`?? Isn't it?

Comment: I think he meant `sum(qList)\len(qList)`

Comment: it's just a piece of my code from a program that calculates grades and it removes the lowest quiz scores (qList) and then factors for 10% of the overall grade. it just feels like i didn't need 3 lines

Comment: and yes i had it dividing by 100 and just realized how stupid that looks lol

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be.

```
qAvg = sum(sorted(qList)[2:])/1
```

`sorted` gives you a sorted list, and `[2:]` is a list [slice](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice).

Answer (score 3):

may be try this:

```
qAvg=sum(sorted(qList)[2:])/(len(qList)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what you intended to achieve, you can also look forward to use heapq module

```
>>> qList = [randint(1,100) for _ in range(10)]
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.heapify(qList)
>>> sum(heapq.nsmallest(len(qList) - 2, qList))/(len(qList) - 2)
50
```

Comment: He wanted less lines, not more.

Comment: @frb: Less line is not always Pythonic.

Comment: @frb That doesn't make it a good idea. The OP doesn't always know what is a good idea, and while I feel this answer could use more explanation and comparison as a method, it's valid.

Comment: @Abhijit & Lattyware — I'm well aware. That doesn't change that the question stills asks if it can be done in a shorter way.

Comment: @frb A -1 means, from the hover text itself, that "This answer was not *useful*." - something different to exactly what the OP asks for can be useful.

Comment: Note that `heapq.nsmallest()` should be preferred only if the number of items to be fetched are very small compared to size of the heap.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Yes its always a Tradeoff, "To Sort or Not To Sort, that is the Question"